# Adapt Text to WearOS Circular Screen with Android Compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, wear-os

I'm using Android Compose to develop a wearOS app. On my pixel watch, which have a rounded screen, I don't succeed in displaying the text correctly without it to be cropped.

My code is the following :

```
Scaffold {
        Column(
            modifier = modifier
                .fillMaxSize()
                .padding(vertical = Dimensions.xsPadding),
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.SpaceBetween
        ) {
                Text(
                    game.game_name,
                    style = MaterialTheme.typography.body1.copy(
                        fontWeight = FontWeight.Bold,
                    ),
                    textAlign = TextAlign.Center,
                    maxLines = 2,
                    overflow = TextOverflow.Ellipsis,
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(horizontal = Dimensions.xsPadding),
                )
                .......
       }
}
```

And here is the result of what I have with a long text :

[cropped text example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xDKlL.png)

Answer (score 0):

You could apply the [fillMaxRectangle](https://github.com/google/horologist/blob/f329439d3db86ee0ec3aecd1a43dd13e5544a720/compose-layout/src/main/java/com/google/android/horologist/compose/layout/FillMaxRectangle.kt#L40) modifier from [Horologist](https://github.com/google/horologist#-compose-layout) to your `Column`:

```kotlin
        Column(
            modifier = modifier
                .fillMaxRectangle()
            ...
        ) {
                ...
       }
```

Comment: Thanks, that work :) But it loses too much space for me. I wanted more something adapting the rounded screen rather then using square in a circle